# prove $G\cap \overline A=\emptyset $

Tags: metric-spaces

I have metric $X$ and $A\subset X$ also there is $G$ an open subset of $X$ so that $G\cap A=\emptyset 
 $
goal:prove that $G\cap \overline A=\emptyset $

Let us suppose there is a $x\in G\cap \overline A$.
So because $x\in G$ for every $ε>0$ there is$$B(x,\varepsilon)\subset G\tag1$$ for every  $ x\in G $.
Also because $x\in \overline A$,$$B(x,e)\cap A\neq \emptyset\tag2.$$ From $(1)$, $(2)$, $G\cap A\neq \emptyset $ which is not true meaning that
$G\cap A= \emptyset $ and therefore $G\cap \overline A=\emptyset $

Is this correct?

Comment: @SolubleFish that is what i did i misstyped the question let me edit it

Comment: For every $\epsilon >0$ in line 3 is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Line $(1)$ is true for some $\epsilon >0$ (and therefore for all $\epsilon$ smaller than that), not for *all* $\epsilon >0$.

The rest is basically correct : taking one such $\epsilon >0$, you can find $y \in A\cap B(x,\epsilon) \subset G$. Then $y\in A\cap G$, which is absurd. Therefore, there can be no $x\in G\cap \bar A$.

**Another way to do this :** Since $G$ is open, $X-G$ is closed and $A\subset X-G$. By definition, $\bar{A}$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ with $A \subset \bar{A}$. Therefore, $\bar{A}\subset X-G$

Comment: Oh ye i just noticed i had the definition of an open set wrong in my mind this whole time

Comment: Nice alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \not \in A$, and $x \in G \cap \overline{A}$.

Then  $x \in G$ and $x \in A'$, set of limit points of $A$.

$x \in G$, open, there is a $N_r(x) \subset G$, $r>0.$

Since $x$ is a limit point of $A$,  $N_r(x) \cap A \not=\emptyset$.

A contradiction  to $G \cap A=\emptyset$.